# Can I say: "(...) state-of-art..."

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-usage

Can I say for example *"I’m working as an engineer in company which provide state of the art IT solution.*"?

I wonder if I can use phrase *"state of the art"* with nouns like:

- IT solution
- oil service
- financial manager

Comment: Why couldn't you use it? The adjective, when in front of a noun is: state-of-the-art machinery. It takes dashes.

Comment: Definition of state of the art: 

: the level of development (as of a device, procedure, process, technique, or science) reached at any particular time usually as a result of modern methods.  - M-W

Comment: But it could apply to a financial manager who was a droid.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "state-of-the-art" is used to refer to things (whether concrete or abstract), not to people.

So these are ok:

> We sell state-of-the-art IT solutions.
>
> Using a state-of-the-art oil service can extend the life of your car.

But this is not:

> My friend Bill is a state-of-the-art financial manager.

Comment: a company can be referred to as a financial manager....but you are right; it does not refer to people.